# The ru_maxrss field obtained by the getrusage function cannot be reduced?

Tags: c

When using getrusage to dynamically monitor memory usage, the ru_maxrss field obtained by the getrusage function cannot be reduced, see the following code to test this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main() {
    struct rusage usage;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    printf("Before allocating memory：Memory usage: %ld KB\n", usage.ru_maxrss);
    sleep(1);
    int *arr =malloc(sizeof(int)*1024*8*1024);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    printf("After allocating memory：Memory usage: %ld KB\n", usage.ru_maxrss);
    sleep(1);
    free(arr);
    printf("After release：Memory usage: %ld KB\n", usage.ru_maxrss);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Here is the output
Before allocating memory: Memory usage: 2592 KB
After allocating memory: Memory usage: 2592 KB
After release:Memory usage: 2592 KB
```

Is there any way I can see the memory usage in real time, as it is logical that the maximum resident set size, as indicated by the ru_maxrss field, decreases as memory is released;
If either I have the wrong idea, please help me to correct it so that I can use getrusage to monitor memory usage dynamically

Comment: It it the maximum used, like said in the man page. That can't possibly go down.

Comment: Ok thank you, so is there a function under linux that can dynamically monitor memory usage?

Comment: You can parse `/proc/self/status`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this approach, but parsing /proc/self/status does not allow real-time monitoring, is there a more real-time method?

Comment: The reason why using /proc/self/status does not support real-time monitoring is that the information in that file is only updated when it is read, and does not reflect the current process status in real time like a memory-mapped file does. In addition, the operation of reading the file itself consumes some system resources, so real time monitoring is not possible. In addition, since /proc/self/status provides a large amount of information, each read needs to read the entire file once, which also leads to a slow read speed and cannot meet the high requirements for real-time applications.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Comment: Ok thank you, I have finished the revision